# wxWidgets: scalable custom control

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create custom control in wxWidgets that will look like this:

[custom control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ylW.png)

It contatins wxTextCtrl and wxBitmapButton. It's rather easy to create it, but my goal is to create scalable control that will look the same in XP, Vista, Win 7, Win 8, Mac OS X.

Usually native controls adjust their size when user changes font size in OS (125%, 150%, 200%).
In my case such control should increase size of wxTextCtrl and increase size of wxBitmapButton and image in this button.

That's why my questions are:

1. How can I create scalable Image in wxBitmapButton? (maybe I should use vector images like .svg? )
2. How can I recognize that I should increase image size in wxBitmapButton?

**I'm not going to use native controls**, because I want them to look the same in all OSs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no portable way to react to the system font size changes in wxWidgets so the best you can do is to respect the font size in effect during your program start up. And for this it's enough to simply use `GetTextExtent()` or `GetChar{Height,Width}()` methods of either `wxWindow` or `wxDC` instead of hard coding the values in pixels in your program.

Comment: Thank you! And what about scalable image? In my opinion the only way is to use vector images. How do peaple solve this issue? I tried to use big images and scale them, but it looks awful when size is like 16*16

Comment: Vector images would look bad too at these sizes. The usual approach is to have a manually drawn bitmap in a few sizes (16, 24, 32, ...) and choose the one closest to what you need.